# Can I use "I was" in the second conditional structure?

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

I know that I should write "**I were**" in the following sentence, but I wonder whether writing "**I was**" is grammatically acceptable.

> *I'd prepare well for the interview if **I was** in your shoes because I heard that they have a tough one.*

Comment: A great many native English speakers would say **if I was** instead of using the traditional subjunctive form **if I were**. As to whether it is grammatically acceptable, I think the answer is that it depends on whom. I don't like it but many people now find it idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd prepare well for the interview if I was/were in your shoes because I heard that they have a tough one

It is just a matter of style. "If I was" is widely accepted as informal standard English and many native speakers find it idiomatic.

"Were", on the other hand, is highly formal and more commonly written than spoken. In *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*, Huddleston and Pullum describe it as an untidy relic of an earlier system:

> The irrealis mood form is unique to *be*, and limited to
> the 1st and 3rd person singular. It is an untidy relic of an earlier system, and some speakers usually, if not always, use preterite *was* instead. (p. 59)